# Domain name name repeated in the URL -- what is wrong with my Joomla/nginx setup?

Tags: url, joomla, nginx

I have a joomla site being served from an nginx server with the following config

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name heftpathology.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    root /var/www/vhosts/heftpathology.com/httpdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
    # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # deny running scripts inside writable directories
    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
            return 403;
           error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }

    # caching of files 
    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
            expires 1y;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
            expires 14d;
}

}
```

As per joomla docs.

However URLs are being served as:

```
http://heftpathology.com/heftpathology.com/index.php
```

i.e. With the site name twice in them.

Comment: Check your php scripts. Probably you forgot to add protocol to your links

Comment: Yep what they said ^ or you have a typo in your global config base URL in Joomla.

Comment: Silly question but have you enabled SEF within Joomla's control panel?

Comment: not a silly question! I was trying to restore from an Akeeba back up, worked fine on a mac server as a test, when moving onto production debian server where issue occurred. Looked in database and config file, SEF is indeed enabled. Ive disabled and now works great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not related to Nginx setup, instead it was a setting to enable SEF in Joomla's database. Disabling SEF stopped the issue from occurring.

A restore to local OS X server did not show the issue after initial installation, it occurred however after a Debian installation.